# erro installing gcc /usr/include/asm/bitsperlong.h:4:42: fatal error: uapi/asm-generic/bitsperlong.h: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, gcc, debian-jessie

I'm relatively a newbie on linux. I'm trying to install GCC v 6.3.0 to use it with Eclipse neon.2 but, after successfully launched the `srcdir/configure` in my objdir (/usr/local/gcc-6.3.0), when I launch the `sudo make bootstrap` command in the terminal under objdir path I return this error:

```
/usr/include/asm/bitsperlong.h:4:42: 
fatal error: uapi/asm-generic/bitsperlong.h: no such file or directory
 #include <uapi/asm-generic/bitsperlong.h>
```

I tried also to install the linux-header-3.2.0-4-rt-amd64 and I'm working on Debian 8.7

Comment: You should compile `GCC` under your home directory so you don't need to be `root` (unless you want to *install* it system wide).

Comment: What options did you pass to `configure`? And did you try just typing `make`?

Comment: Followed the instructions on GCC website who suggest to separate src and obj folders, giving /usr/local as the default objdir folder and not to install too deep in home 'cause in some system can generate issues.

No options at all excpet for -lean option to save space on disk. Yes I tried but the error was the same.

Now I'll try another installation on a VM in my home desktop

Comment: According to this: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/ you should use `--prefix=/usr/local` (by default) as a parameter to your configure script. I can't find where it says to put your build folder under `/usr/local` that is very unusual (I would say **wrong**). I would put the source code somewhere like `$HOME/dev/gcc` and use `$HOME/dev/gcc-build` as your `objdir` folder. Read through this page carefully noting the relevant configuration options: https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html

Comment: I recently used these `configure` options for a (relatively) fast build: `--prefix=/opt/gcc-6.3.0 --program-suffix=-6.3.0 --enable-threads=posix --disable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-stage1-checking --disable-multilib`

Comment: The above config installs the compiler at `/opt/gcc-6.3.0/bin/g++-6.3.0`.

Comment: @Galik It seem I solved the problem reinstalling debian from the scratch, then quite all the prerequisites by hand and not only with the gcc release embedded script and at last installing g++-multilib. To be sure I don't miss anything this time I run everything under auto-apt. Is it normal that the compiling is taking more than 24 hours?

Comment: yes it seems normal, now the bootstrap is comparing stage 2 and 3. However I used a complete lean bootstrap always under auto-apt.